# How to search data inside multi-dimensional in each array result in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to search in each array if Transaction_No is 0 echo Barcode found if not found skip search in next array.

expected result:
     0020000023120

```
Array(
     [0] => Array
        (
          [Barcode] => 0020000021119
          [Transaction_No] => 1
         )

     [1] => Array
       (
         [Barcode] => 0020000023120
         [Transaction_No] => 0
        )

       [2] => Array
       (
         [Barcode] => 0020000023999
         [Transaction_No] => 0
        )

     )


       $customer = $response->ReadMultiple_Result->coupon;    

        foreach($customer as $value) {
          if (current($value->Transaction_No) == "0") {
              echo $value->Barcode.'</br>'; 
             }
         }
```

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: yes but it shows both barcode with transaction_no 0         foreach ($customer as $value) {
                                  if ($value->Transaction_No == "0") {
                                       echo $value->Barcode.'</br>'; 
                                     }
                          }

Comment: why is that a problem? that's what you want: print each barcode where transaction is 0. you have two 0's in there, so you get two barcodes. or do you mean skip the 23999 barcode, because you found 23120?

Comment: If you wrote some code - put it in the question so it will be easier to help

Comment: what i want is only show the latest barcode 0020000023120 not both barcodes 0020000023120 and 0020000023999

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
Foreach ( $array as $value ) 
 {

        if ($value['Transaction_No'] === 1 ) {
            echo $value['barcode'];
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer already just add break; So it returns me the latest array barcode with transaction 0.

```
 foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    if ($value['Transaction_No'] == '0' ) {
        echo $value['barcode'];
        break;
    } 
 }
```